# Stop the selectionChanged event when handling item tapped events

Tags: gridview, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to stop the selection of a gridview item when tapping on an item. Every time I tap an item it selects it and bring up the app bar.

The problem is, is that I need to handle the item tapped and item swipe selection events independently.

I want the item tap event to bind another listview on the page.. while I want the item swipe-select or right click to select the item and bring up the app bar.

I have the selectionChanged action working.. But it is working too well. It fires every time I tap an item. So I added the property to the grid item, IsTapEnabled="False". I've changed the location of my item tapped event handlers from the grid item to the gridview and still the selectionChanged event always fires.

Is there a way to stop the selectionChanged event for a gridview from getting fired off while handling item tapped events for its items?

Thanks!

gridview XAML:

```
            <GridView x:Name="GridViewName" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0, 75, 0, 0"
                      CanReorderItems="True" CanDragItems="True" 
                      SelectionChanged="GridViewTasks_SelectionChanged_1" 
                      IsTapEnabled="False" Tapped="Grid_Tapped_1">
                <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Style="{Binding Style}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                              Width="250" Height="150" 
                              Drop="VariableSizedWrapGrid_Drop_1" AllowDrop="True" >
                         ...
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemTemplate>
            </GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need following code in your `GridView`

```
IsSwipeEnabled="True" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="ItemClick"
```